# WPF Listboxitem text wrap

Tags: c#, wpf

So I got this RSS feed which I want to add to a certain part of the application window, so I'm using a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" Width="600" Height="550"  Margin="50" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="#443266" />
```

To bind the data from C#, I do this:

```
List<ListBoxItem> rssFeedList;

foreach (var item in myFeed)
{
    foreach (Item i in item.Items)
    {
        ListBoxItem tb = new ListBoxItem();
        tb.FontSize = 20.0;
        tb.Content = i.Title + "\n";
        tb.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        tb.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
        rssFeedList.Add(tb);
    }
}

...

listbox1.ItemsSource = rssFeedList;
```

Just now, the application is fine, except that longer titles are not wrapped so appear off the Listbox, which I can't figure out.

Not sure whether this is the best UIElement to use neither? All I need is each RSS title to be displayed within a box.

Comment: Oh, I was experimenting with TextBlocks.

Comment: `tb.Content = new TextBlock { Text = i.Title + "\n", TextWrapping = TextWrapping. };` [`TextWrapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx)

Comment: That works great jberger, ty. :) - wish I'd thought of that ages ago!

Comment: @jberger: Turn your comment into an answer that can be accepted. Others will know that an answer was found and it will increase your reputation.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes you make a good point, but sometimes once a user gets what they're looking for, they don't come back.. until their next question ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tb.Content = new TextBlock { Text = i.Title + "\n", TextWrapping = TextWrapping. };`

choose your desired [`TextWrapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx)